# When im playing minecraft and press f3 g or fn f3 g It doesn't show the chunk borders why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I'm playing Minecraft and press <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> It doesn't show the chunk borders.

I have disabled reduced bug info. I also have a laptop that the F3 button is the volume button. I am playing in v1.15.2

Comment: "Reduced bug info"? So you have blocked Mojira in your firewall? :D (It's actually called "reduced **de**bug info".)

Comment: Do other combinations work for you, like F3+B?